# Accessing the <apex:pageMessages> tag in visualforce through javascript/jquery (without apex controller)

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

```
<apex:pageMessages id="barmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
```

I need to access this tag in visualforce page and set value to this tag using javascript/jquery based on certain conditions.
What I have done so far is:

```
   $("[id$='barmsg']").each(function( index )
   {
       document.getElementById('{!$Component.barmsg}').innerHTML = "Wrong Value";
   }
```

But I'am not able to access it.

Comment: First of all selecting by ID is only going to return one result so I don't think .each is the proper method to be accessing. Second just do `$("#barmsg")` to select the id. That aside, make sure your code is run after the pageMessages element is loaded.

Comment: hi Blakethepatton, I tried using this                                     $("#barmsg").text('Length should be 10 characters');
                   $("#barmsg").show();    but it is still not working

Comment: Are you sure that your code is running after `barmsg` is loaded onto the page? Try running your code in the your browser console (F12).

Comment: It should be noted that using jquery to modify the content of that container is not the best way. You might check out modifying the actual error response. Check out [this discussion on the salesforce forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098yhIAA).

Comment: thanks Blakethepathon , What I actually want to do is ,  I want to add an error message just below an input field( in addition to the alert box) if it does not satisfy the custom validation code written in javascript. But I don't want to use apex controller for it for certain reasons.So is there any way to do so using jquey or javascript

Comment: I'm not sure since I've never used salesforce or visualforce. It looks like they're using something like angular to render that custom tag so accessing it would have to come after angular has finished rendering the webpage. If that's the case then it'd just be a matter of catching when the page has finished rendering and then running your custom jquery code after that. 

You could try something like:

```$('#barmsg').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  //your code here
});```

Though you'd have to check [browser support](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php) for that event

Comment: Oh nevermind, it looks like `DOMSubtreeModified` is deprecated so you might try and see if they have set up any events and then you could bind to and bind to one of those.